# (programmatic) Position of divs, what property should one use?

Tags: javascript, css, html, position

I would like to get/set the position of divs. I don't know what's the best technique one should use:

The CSS style?

```
var x = aDiv.style.left;
var y = aDiv.style.top;
```

or use the HTML div element's clientTop/clientLeft?

or... ?

Thanks for your time!
J.

Comment: The purpose of this is to programmatically move the divs on a fixed framerate, the scope of my question is to know which one is "best" in any imaginable ways, like cross browser, best practices, performance, etc.
thanks.

Comment: is jquery an option? using jquery will fix most of your cross browser and performance issues.

Comment: I would do that with a JS framework. Mootools and jQuery, for example, have great methods to set/get div positions, you have not to worry about anything than calling them. And they are cross browser, a huge advantage. But it's better if you wait for answers using vanilla JS, maybe it's too much to include a JS framework only to do that.

Comment: I'll check the jquery utilities for moving sprites then, yep, jquery is an option :-) Thanks

Comment: err, move divs, not sprites I meant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clientTop` and `clientLeft` are read-only, so you can't set the div position with them. There are multiple ways to do it with CSS, I suggest you study the basics of [CSS positioning](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/).

Comment: Hey thanks for the read-only info. I just wanted to know which way was best, setting offsets or css styles?

Comment: It really depends on how you want positioned elements to interact with other elements on the page. If you don't want them to affect other elements, you take them out of the flow with realtive or absolute positioning, then manipulate `style.left` and `style.top` as you mentioned.